# How to send data in Flask to another page?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using **Flask** to make a tickets booking app. But for now I'm little confused on how to send data from one page to another page, like this snippet of code:

```
@app.route('/index', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        date = request.form['date']
        return redirect(url_for('main.booking', date=date))
    return render_template('main/index.html')


@app.route('/booking')
def booking():
    return render_template('main/booking.html')
```

The **`date`** variable is a request from a form, and for now I want to send the **`date`** data to `booking` function. What is term for that purpose..?

Comment: did you try session storage ? redirect method doesn't allow send data to another page.

Comment: I'm reading about it now @VillageMonkey, but still thinking about, should I use session or cookies in this case..?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Passing data is possible for `get` request from one route to another.

You are almost there to get the submitted `date` value in `booking` route.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = request.form.get('date')
        return redirect(url_for('booking', date=date))
    return render_template('main/index.html')


@app.route('/booking')
def booking():
    date = request.args.get('date', None)
    return render_template('main/booking.html', date=date)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`main/index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h3>Home page</h3>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <label for="date">Date: </label>
      <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`main/booking.html`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h3>Booking page</h3>
    <p>
      Seleted date: {{ date }}
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

Home route with a form to submit the date

[image: home route]

Getting the date in booking route

[image: getting the date in booking route]

**Disadvantages:**

- The values (e.g.: `date`) are passed as URL parameters from one route to another.
- Anyone with a get request can access the second part (e.g. `booking` route).

**Alternatives:**

- Use session storage.
- Use Ajax to facilitate multi-part forms.

Comment: Why if passing value as URL parameters including to disadvantages?

Comment: It depends on the data. If the data contains sensitive information (e.g.: password) it should not be send via URL parameters.

Comment: Does this way are secure for this case..?, or what is the best practice to send data like my questions..?, or should I using session..?

Comment: If you are not passing any sensitive values via URL parameters, you may use this. Otherwise, try session storage.

Comment: Thanks very much for the best explanation @arsho , I got lots of knowledge from you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use flask session to send data from one page to another page.

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, url_for, redirect, 
 session

 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = request.form.get('date')
        session["date"] = date
        return redirect(url_for('booking', date=date))
    return render_template('main/index.html')


 @app.route('/booking')
 def booking():
    date = session.get("date")
    return render_template('main/booking.html', date=date)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```